# Обрезать строки после запятой

Tags: php

Написал вот такой код. Скрипт работает, но не совсем, обрезает только первую строку.

```
<?php
    $str = file_get_contents("slova.txt");
    $str = implode(',',array_slice(explode(',', $str),0,1)); 
    echo $str; //
    ?>

slova.txt - пример
slovo 1,69,19,28 %,"6,6"
slovo 2,52,12,23 %,"5,6"
slovo 3,57,9,16 %,"4,1"
slovo 4,45,9,20 %,"6,3"
slovo 5,33,6,18 %,"3,7"
```

Нужно, чтобы скрипт вывел все слова так же в каждой новой строке, а не только первое.

Comment: $str = strtr($str, ',','');

Comment: http://www.php.su/strtr

Comment: Не работает так у меня.

Comment: @jikol, а потому что он написал вообще не то :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [функцию fgets()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fgets.php), по идее у вас должен получиться вот такой код:

```
<?php
     $str = @fopen("slova.txt",  "r");
     if ($str) {
         while (($bufferStr = fgets($str, 4096)) !== false) {
             $bufferStr = implode(',',array_slice(explode(',', $bufferStr),0,1)); 
             echo $bufferStr;
         }
    }
    fclose($str);
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, все прекрасно работает. -)